# Loopback in Yosemite not working

Tags: macos, dns

I'm on Yosemite (10.10.2). Since upgrading I got some DNS issues, it seems my loopback isn't working any more. When I'm talking to my app locally via `http://localhost:port`, localhost in some cases (sorry for being vague here) gets resolved to my current local IP. (observed with rails and openstack)

some analysis:

```
mac:~ me$ scutil -r localhost
Reachable,Local Address,Directly Reachable Address
mac:~ me$ scutil -r loopback
Not Reachable
```

etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost 
fe80::1%lo0     localhost
```

etc/networks:

```
loopback        127             loopback-net
```

And a maybe related issue: DNS sometimes stops working completely. The only thing that helps, is a force quit of the `discoveryd` process.

I appreciate any help guiding me in the right direction to solve this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you been able to find a solution to this?

Comment: My workaround is to always use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost, luckily that was configurable everywhere I needed it.

Answer (score 1):

This might possibly be not the best long-term solution - I can't fully test as I don't actually have active IPv6 from my ISP yet, only on my local network.

I simply set my hosts file to

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             127.0.0.1 
fe80::1%lo0     127.0.0.1
```

which has so far given no noticeable issues.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but well this does not solve the loopback issue:
`mac:~ me$ scutil -r localhost
   Reachable,Local Address
   mac:~ me$ scutil -r loopback
   Not Reachable`

so the only thing that changed is, that localhost isn't a 'Directly Reachable Address' any more